# Python parse at any nested level and get highest attribute value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyyaml

I've an assignment and I've been trying to solve this for hours with no avail. paper records can be found nested at any level in the dictionary

I'm trying to Parse a yaml file and get the nested values where the output is

```
sales                      highest_sales
sales.yml/sales1/paper1       Dwight
```

So far, I'm only able to get key and value pair off my code but I've gone anywhere. Can anyone please spare a thought

This is the output from YAML file

```
{'sales1': {'paper1': {'Jim': 8, 'Pam': 9, 'Dwight': 43}}, 'sales2': {'morning_sales': {'paper2': {'Jim': 10, 'Pam': 23, 'Dwight': 67, 'Michael': 12}}, 'evening_sales': {'paper3': {'Jim': 3, 'Pam': 43, 'Dwight': 67}}}, 'paper4': {'Jim': 23, 'Pam': 14, 'Dwight': 8}}
```

```
import yaml

with open(r"C:\Users\Jason\Assignments\Assignment8\sales.yml", 'r') as yamlfile:
        data = yaml.load(yamlfile, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)  


def iterdict(d):
  for k,v in d.items():        
     if isinstance(v, dict):
         iterdict(v)
     else:            
         print (k,":",v)

iterdict(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key for the maximum value can be found using `operator.itemgetter` [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

You can try this code, It should work

```
import yaml
import operator

def check_max(k, v, prev_key):
    try:
        # To get key of maximum sale
        sales = max(v.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
        if 'sales' in sales or 'paper' in sales:
            # To check if value is another dictionary
            raise Exception("value is a dictionary")
        print("{:38s} {:10s}".format(str(prev_key)+'/'+str(k),sales))

    except:
        # The value was a dictionary 
        for k1, v1 in v.items():
            check_max(k1,v1, prev_key+'/'+str(k))


with open(r"C:\Users\Jason\Assignments\Assignment8\sales.yml", 'r') as yamlfile:
        data = yaml.load(yamlfile, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)  

# Formatting of data you can 
# increase the value for proper formatting
print("{:38s} {:10s}".format("sales","highest_sales"))
for k,v in data.items():
    check_max(k,v, 'sales.yml')
```

Output:

```
sales                                  highest_sales
sales.yml/sales1/paper1                Dwight
sales.yml/sales2/morning_sales/paper2  Dwight
sales.yml/sales2/evening_sales/paper3  Dwight
sales.yml/paper4                       Jim
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the guidance and the for providing the documentation. I really appreacite